# Required: com.app.appname.mainactivity, Found: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

I just started to work in android studio. Tutorials are helping and all, but I can't find any help for this problem (it might be obvious, but I don't see it).
My problem comes after implementing the communication between the fragment activity and main activity.
Error after compiling is:

> error: incompatible types: FragmentActivity cannot be converted to MainActivity

After going to where the error is, it says:

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required: com.app.appname.mainactivity
>
> Found: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

This is the code for my fragment, where the error happens:

(names are in my language)

```
package com.ors.herobomb;


import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Uspeh extends Fragment {

    EditText upis;
    Button poslji;

    public Uspeh() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View p = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uspeh, container, false);

        upis = p.findViewById(R.id.hero);
        poslji = p.findViewById(R.id.poslji);

        poslji.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String ode = upis.getText().toString();
                if(ode.length()>1){
                    MainActivity main = getActivity();
                    main.send(ode);
                }
            }
        });

        return p;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding an explicit cast: `MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();`

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by Daniel.

Replacing:

```
MainActivity main = getActivity();
```

With:

```
MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

Solved my problem.